# Comparing date between date selected with date from the database

Tags: php, sql, database, date, compare

I have problem with comparing date selected and with date in the table attendance in the database.

Below is **table attendance.**

[image: table attendance]

**Table student**

[image: table student]

**Table teacher**

[image: table teacher]

```
$class = getfield('class');
$getdata = mysql_query("select * from student where 
         class = '$class' order by name ")     or die(mysql_query);
$getstud = mysql_query("select birth_no from student where class = '$class'") or die(mysql_query);
$getdate = mysql_query("select date from attendance where birth_no = '$getstud'");

if(isset($_POST['date'])){

    $date = $_POST['date'];
    if($date == $getdate){
        //do someting
    }
    else{
        echo 'Date not matched!';
    }
}
```

I try to execute above code, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me to tell me how to compare date from table attendance with selected date by using birth_no from table student?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to fetch data to a variable, then you can select it from array, try this:

```
$class = getfield('class');
$getdata = mysql_query("select * from student where class = '$class' order by name ")     or die(mysql_query);

$result = mysql_query("select birth_no from student where class = '$class'") or die(mysql_query);

$getstud = mysql_fetch_row($result);

$result = mysql_query("select date from attendance where birth_no = '$getstud[0]'");

$getdate = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $getdate[0];
```

but you **should not** use `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated and will not be supported in future. Instead use `mysli_` procedural functions or class http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php